# code works fine on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: java, hibernate, session, tomcat, struts2

i have experience in android, but not familiar with hibernate and advance java. But i have to fix this issue.Please suggest.

the problem is that,
Below code works fine on my tomcat local host server.
but shows the errors on remote server.
when i login it says "invalid login" try the same two or three times it login with the same id password.

```
public String Login() {
        boolean isValidUser = applicationManager.isValidUser(getUserName(), getUserPassword());

        if (isValidUser == false) {
            if (getLang()!=null && getLang().equals("de")) {
                setLang("de");
                addActionMessage("Ungültige Anmeldung");
            } else {
                setLang("en");
                addActionMessage("Invalid login");
            }
            return ERROR;
        } else { 
            session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            session.put("loggedIn","true");
            session.put("userName", getUserName());
            session.put("userPassword", getUserPassword());

            try {

                HttpSession session1;
                session1 = ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession();
                session1.setAttribute("lang", getLang());
                session1.setAttribute("loggedIn", "true");
                session1.setAttribute("userName", getUserName());
                session1.setAttribute("userPassword", getUserPassword());
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.countryList = applicationManager.getCountries();
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

HibernateUtil.java :

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
        try{
            // create session factory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch(Throwable ex){
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

UserManager.java :

```
public class UserManager extends HibernateUtil{

    public ArrayList<User> validateUser(String userName,String userPassword){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        ArrayList<User> userList =  new ArrayList<User>();
        try{
            Query query = session.createQuery("from User where userName=:userName and userPassword=:userPassword");
            query.setString("userName", userName);
            query.setString("userPassword", userPassword);
            for(Iterator itr = query.iterate();itr.hasNext();){
                User user = (User) itr.next();
                userList.add(user);
            }
            return userList;
        }catch(HibernateException he){
            he.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return userList; 
    }
}
```

Hiberanate.cfg.xml looks like this :

> ```
>     <hibernate-configuration>
>       <session-factory>
>           <property name="connection.driver_class">
>               com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>           </property>
>
>           <property name="connection.url">
>               jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/xxxxx
>           </property>
>
>           <property name="connection.username">samir</property>
>           <property name="connection.password">samir</property>
>           <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
>           <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
>           <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
>           <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
>           <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
>           <property name="c3p0.timeout">100</property> <!-- seconds -->               
>           <property name="dialect">
>               org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>           </property>
>           <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
>           <property name="cache.provider_class">
>               org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
>           </property>
>           <property name="show_sql">true</property>
>           <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
>
>           <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
>
>
>           <mapping class="login.model.User" />
>
>       </session-factory>
>     </hibernate-configuration>
> ```

log :

```
  Hibernate: /* from User where userName=:userName and userPassword=:userPassword */ select user0_.USER_ID as col_0_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.USER_NAME=? and user0_.USER_PASSWORD=?
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query using iterate
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.iterate(QueryLoader.java:450)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.iterate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performIterate(HQLQueryPlan.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.iterate(SessionImpl.java:1219)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.iterate(QueryImpl.java:69)
    at application.controller.ApplicationManager.isValidUser(ApplicationManager.java:177)
    at application.view.ApplicationAction.Login(ApplicationAction.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed due to underlying exception/error:


** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
MESSAGE: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.

STACKTRACE:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 47 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2763)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3299)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2543)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1737)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1888)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at application.controller.ApplicationManager.getCountries(ApplicationManager.java:34)
    at application.view.ApplicationAction.execute(ApplicationAction.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2774)
    ... 86 more


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4004)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.iterate(QueryLoader.java:422)
    ... 71 more
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query using iterate
```

Comment: where is your connectivity code?

Comment: Works in localhost but not in Remote means. What is the change. Tomcat runs in both IP and Localhost. Are you just trying the url without doing any change?
Also Is your MySQL configured to work for IP. Because localhost and IP are treated differently sometimes

Comment: yes MySQL is configured. it works fine when i run the code in my machine using eclipse but whe i deploy war file in remote server it works sometime some time not..as i said in my question i can login with the same id password after trying two or three times

Comment: What is the exact error, Exception? check tomcat logs.

Comment: you said "invalid login"? that mean are you sure connection has been established to remote server? Also check remote server port blocked or not?

Comment: where is your mysql DB is it on same remote machine or any other place.

Comment: @ILLA : if the problem is related to connection it should not works not even a single time. but sometimes it login successfully mean when you try 3-4 times it login successfully

Comment: @Sura mysql DB is on different remote machine.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace for the error? I would expect to see a CAUSED BY section after the bit that has been posted. Please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Your database is intermittantly dropping the connection on you - is there any further info available in the database logs?

Answer (score 3):

(Not an answer, but some code notes.)

1) Name functions with a lower case letter, e.g.:

```
public String login() { ... }
```

2) Use canonical Java for checking booleans, e.g.:

```
if (!isValidUser) { ... }
```

3) Use variable names that make canonical code "read" properly, e.g.:

```
if (!validUser) { ... }
```

4) Remove the need for null checks when doing string compares, e.g.:

```
if ("de".equals(getLang()) { ... }
```

Also, it's not clear to me if `setLang()` is just a setter for what's retrieved with `getLang()`; that's a little confusing and makes that chunk of code kind of weird without further knowledge.

5) Don't put the valid user code in the same conditional; if it's an invalid user, treat it as a special case and return. The valid user code is then differentiated from the guard clause, e.g.:

```
if (!validUser) {
    // actionMessage stuff.
    return ERROR;
} 

session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
// The rest of valid user code.
```

6) Use booleans for booleans, e.g.:

```
session.put("loggedIn", true);
```

7) Use constants for scoped variables, e.g.:

```
session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put(SessionKeys.LOGGED_IN, true);
```

8) Use `SessionAware`, it makes testing easier; `session` is then just an action property:

```
session.put(SessionKeys.LOGGED_IN, true);
```

9) Don't name something `session1` when it's a completely different thing... and in this case, it isn't even a different thing, so you're putting the same information in twice.

10) Be consistent when accessing action properties; don't use `setXxx()` *and* `this.xxx`. Most of the time you can just use `xxx` anyway.

```
setCountryList(applicationManager.getCountries()); // Or, my preference in most cases:
countryList = appManager.getCountries();
```

11) Don't name variables by their type, except in situations where you need to specifically differentiate, e.g.:

```
countries = appManager.getCountries();
```

This leaves us with a more-manageable:

```
public String Login() {
    if (!appManager.isValidUser(username, password)) {
        handleInvalidUser();
        return ERROR;
    } 

    session.put(SessionKeys.LANG,          lang);
    session.put(SessionKeys.LOGGED_IN,     true);
    session.put(SessionKeys.USER_NAME,     username);
    session.put(SessionKeys.USER_PASSWORD, password);

    countries = appManager.getCountries();

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative post.this code is written by one of my colleague who is not available in office and i have to fix the bug...

Answer (score 1):

It seems connectivity issue (Delay response) with your remote server to mysqlDB server

Replace this

```
for(Iterator itr = query.iterate();itr.hasNext();){
            User user = (User) itr.next();
            userList.add(user);
        }
        return userList;
```

by this

```
return (ArrayList<User>)query.list();
```

And try , may be helps to you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an communication problem between your remote server and your database may be firewall.
Which will explain why its working for you in your local.
Make sure you can able to reach the database server from your remote app server.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mysql logs: maybe you reach the maximun number of connection allowed for your mysql user to the server.
The C3p0 max_size must be lower than the max number of connection of the server.