# Mysqli get a warning on remote server but works locally

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following query which works locally but I get warning on remote server.

```
$query_getMainPage = $conCreative->query("SELECT l.*, p.* FROM languagep l INNER JOIN pages p ON (l.languagePageBelongs=p.pageID) WHERE p.pageBelongs=0");
$row_getMainPage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_getMainPage); 
$totalRows_getMainPage = mysqli_num_rows($query_getMainPage);
```

The warning I get is

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in...**

Its the first time I use Mysqli instead of MySql so I guess I am doing something wrong with the way I use the functions.

Comment: See what `$row_getMainPage` is returning to you by simply `var_dump()`ing it.

Comment: It might be some error with code. Take a look at this. Hope it helps.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247702/code-works-fine-on-localhost-but-not-on-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

Of course you're not doing something wrong as it works on the other server.
It's remote server environment responsible for the error.

However, there is one thing you ought to do whether you're using mysql or mysqli - you have to check query result and handle the error.
At least do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM languagep l INNER JOIN pages p 
        ON (l.languagePageBelongs=p.pageID) WHERE p.pageBelongs=0";
$res = $con->query($sql) or trigger_error($con->error."[$sql]");
```

- so, you'll be notified of the mysql error and be able to take appropriate action.

But there is another problem with your code - mysqli.
Do not use mysqli. **Use PDO** instead.
It will save you A LOT of headaches in the future.

PDO is simple yet powerful to use

first, create a connection

```
$dsn  = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost;charset=utf8';
$opt  = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

then use it to run queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM languagep l INNER JOIN pages p 
        ON (l.languagePageBelongs=p.pageID) WHERE p.pageBelongs=0";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$totalRows = $sth->fetchColumn();
```

if you need not only count but all the data too:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM languagep l INNER JOIN pages p 
        ON (l.languagePageBelongs=p.pageID) WHERE p.pageBelongs=0";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
$totalRows = count($data);
```